# spring boot with spring-data-jpa and full tomcat-jdbc config throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for ResetAbandonedTimer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, tomcat-jdbc

I'm using spring boot 1.3.0.RELEASE with the following pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am trying to get JPA working and it all works fine with the following in my application.properties

```
# Connection url for the database
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@**********
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = **********
spring.datasource.password = *********
```

when I switch to full blown dbcp config for tomcat-jdbc as below:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**********
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.initial-size=0
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.default-auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.default-transaction-isolation=2
spring.datasource.fair-queue=false
spring.datasource.jdbc-interceptors=ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;ResetAbandonedTimer"
spring.datasource.jmx-enabled=true
spring.datasource.log-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.max-idle=1
spring.datasource.max-wait=30000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000
spring.datasource.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout=300
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.test-on-return=false
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=false
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=10000
spring.datasource.use-equals=false
spring.datasource.validation-interval=60000
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 2+2 FROM DUAL
```

I get the following stack trace

```
2015-11-20 16:58:18.788 ERROR 48307 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to inform interceptor of pool start.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer" from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@5bbcaf22;ClassLoader:TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
context: ROOT
delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@5bbcaf22
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties$InterceptorDefinition.getInterceptorClass(PoolProperties.java:964) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar:na]\
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:447) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar:na]
......
......
......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:74) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.28.jar:na]
    ... 147 common frames omitted
```

This seems to be the case even with different spring boot versions....
Is my config (taken from a spring datasource bean we already use fine) not what boot expects?

cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typo.

Remove `"` from `spring.datasource.jdbc-interceptors=ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;ResetAbandonedTimer"` at the end there.

Comment: I am indebted to you! Unbelievable! After all these years developing you would think the days of getting bitten by a typo were gone...many thanks! And sorry for wasting bytes!

Comment: I'm glad to help there ;)